# RNGCryptoServiceProvider is obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

I need to generate a token using random numbers and letters. However, the error message is telling me to use RandomNumberGenerator which will only give me random numbers which will not help.

error messsage

> 'RNGCryptoServiceProvider' is obsolete: 'RNGCryptoServiceProvider is obsolete. To generate a random number, use one of the RandomNumberGenerator static methods instead.'

Code currently used

```
    private static string RandomString()
    {
        int length = 256;
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] uintBuffer = new byte[sizeof(uint)];

            while (length-- > 0)
            {
                rng.GetBytes(uintBuffer);
                uint num = BitConverter.ToUInt32(uintBuffer, 0);
                res.Append(valid[(int)(num % (uint)valid.Length)]);
            }
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }
```

How do I change the code above to use a package that is not out of date?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `RandomNumberGenerator` like this:

```
var randomNumber = new byte[32];
string refreshToken = "";

using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
{
     rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
     refreshToken = Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
}
```

Example of result: `fHu4SOyv03PhHvqWx5WGmI5xQFnH00CmLCV3IYJd5Dw=`

Just adjust this to your case.

Comment: is that thread safe?

Comment: FYI to anyone concerned like I was, RandomNumberGenerator is in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace and is documented as providing cryptographically strong randomness. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.getbytes?view=net-7.0