# Can't decrypt password string anymore when closing and starting application again

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

I'm learning C# and am trying to implement a Login Function. I have a registration form, a login form and my data (including this user information) gets saved into an XML File.

I have the following Class:

```
public static class UserController
{
    // Inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657792/how-to-securely-save-username-password-local
    private static readonly byte[] entropy = new byte[20];

    public static string EncryptString(string password)
    {
        // Convert Password to byte[]
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

        // use RandomNumberGenerator instead of using RNGCryptoServiceProvider which is obsolete 
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418725/rngcryptoserviceprovider-is-obsolete
        using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            rng.GetBytes(entropy);
        }

        // Protect (Encrypt) the String
        byte[] ciphertext = ProtectedData.Protect(data, entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

        // return as Base64
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertext);
    }

    public static string DecryptString(string password)
    {
        byte[] plaintext = ProtectedData.Unprotect(Convert.FromBase64String(password), entropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext);
    }


    public static bool CheckLoginCredentials(string username, string password)
    {
        bool isOK = false;
        var myUser = XmlHandler.GetUserFromXml(username);
        if (myUser != null)
        {
            // Decrypt Password
            string plainpassword = DecryptString(myUser.Password);
            if (username == myUser.UserName && password == plainpassword)
                isOK = true;
        }
        return isOK;
    }
}
```

When I create a User in my registration form (which gets his password encrypted with `DecryptString()`) and then Login with that user, everything works.
However, if I close the application and try to login again, the `DecryptString()` can't decrypt the Password to plain text anymore.

Why is that? Do I have to store a key somewhere?

Errormsg:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException
  HResult=0x8007000D
  Nachricht = The data is invalid.
  Quelle = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData
  Stapelüberwachung:
   bei System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.ProtectOrUnprotect(Byte[] inputData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope, Boolean protect)
   bei System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[] encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
   bei Semesterprojekt_ContactManager.UserController.DecryptString(String password) in C:\Install\xxx\UserController.cs: Zeile37
   bei Semesterprojekt_ContactManager.UserController.CheckLoginCredentials(String username, String password) in C:\Install\xxx\UserController.cs: Zeile54
   bei Semesterprojekt_ContactManager.Login_View.CmdLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Install\xxx\Login_View.cs: Zeile22
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: From where do you think you get the correct entropy in DecryptString?

Answer (score 1):

The point of generating `entropy` is that it's random - It's highly unlikely to contain the same values twice in a row, therefore you can't use to decrypt a password after restarting your application.

However, you should never need to decrypt a password - you should just verify it's correct via a hash. See [BCrypt.NET](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net) as an example.